# Asnyc Initialisation of RXJava BehaviorSubject

Tags: java, android, rx-java

[image: Sketch App Structure]

In my Android App I use a BehaviourSubject "to get data" from a data provider to my UI and other services that need the data. For the sake of an example, let's assume these are messages for our user.

Whenever a refresh of the data (e.g. messages) is triggered, the data provider will do a "long running" (aka "slow") network call to retrieve message and feed them into the subject by invoking the subject's `onNext(data)` operation, thus "broadcasting" the update to the UI and the other subscribers.

This works well, but I'm having a problem with the initialisation of the subject or put another way with setting the initial value of the subject on app start.

I know that I can set an initial value via `BehaviorSubject.create(initialValue)`, but as the *initialValue* is the result of the network call, this would block the initialisation of the subject.

I currently do the following in my data provider's init:

```
BehaviorSubject<Data> subject = BehaviorSubject.create();

getDataFromNetwork().subscribe(data -> subject.onNext(data));
```

where `getDataFromNetwork()` returns an Observable for the result of the network call.

**Question:**
The above construct of wiring the observable that refreshes from network by hand into the BehaviourSubject somehow feels *wrong*/not elegant. Is there a better way to initialise a BehaviourSubject with another Observable?

I'm thinking of something like:
`BehaviorSubject.create(Observable obs)` or in my case `BehaviourSubject.create(getDataFromNetwork())` that would setup the subject, leave it empty until the Observable emits something, and then "pushes" this something to its subscribers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What *feels* wrong is that you're using a subject. In Rx it's a general recommendation not to use subjects (as much as possible), and you'd be surprised how much you can achieve w/o them.

In your case you should simply expose an observable instead of the subject:

```
Observable<Data> cachedData = getDataFromNetwork().publish().replay(1);
```

It'll work the same way you're trying to trick `BehaviorSubject` into, but fully Rx.

If you want to refresh the query, then [switch](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/switch.html) is the operator you probably need, e.g. assuming `refreshObs` is an observable which ticks upon refresh:

```
Observable<Data> cachedData = refreshObs.map(t -> getDataFromNetwork())
                                        .switchOnNext()
                                        .publish().replay(1);
```

Comment: How would I feed updated data into the `cachedData` Observable?

Comment: `getDataFromNetwork()` is _feeding_ them, but maybe your question means you want to re-execute the network query from time to time ? if so, on which condition do you do that ?

Comment: Switch + emitting observables of observables ... awesome! Thank you!

Comment: (and to answer your question, refreshing is triggered via time or user-interaction, but that would be just "piping" these events into the refresh-obs, right?)

Comment: yes, eventually with an initial value concat'ed to make sure any observer will get a value, even if no refresh was ever called.

Comment: @Gluck what is the `select` method being called on `refreshObs`? I'm not seeing that.

Comment: @starkej2 `select` is a common alias/alternative for `map` in many Rx implementations, fixed it as this Q is for RxJava, thx !